# What is the best free database to use to get prescription and otc drugs marketed in the U.S. and approved by FDA?

Tags: openfda

I'm working on a project to build a drug database that provides drug lookup and information (indications/use, side effects, interactions, etc.) and also provides pricing by pharmacy networks. So, apart from the drug database where can I get the registered Pharmacy network (NPI) and pricing data?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, openFDA does not that information and we are unable to provide directions to obtain it.

Answer (score 0):

[Historical Structured Product Labels for FDA-Approved Drugs](https://healthdata.gov/dataset/ddod-use-case-historical-structured-product-labels-fda-approved-drugs)

Every prescription drug (including biological drug products) approved by FDA for human use comes with FDA-approved labeling. The openFDA drug product labeling API provides data for prescription and over-the-counter (OTC) drug labeling. Since mid-2009, labeling has been posted publicly in the [Structured Product Labeling (SPL)](https://healthdata.gov/dataset/ddod-use-case-historical-structured-product-labels-fda-approved-drugs/resource/949dffeb-77b3) format.

The openFDA drug product labeling API returns data from the FDA Structured Product Labeling (SPL) dataset. This dataset contains structured documentation about regulated products, submitted by manufacturers to FDA. OpenFDA uses the latest available bulk downloads, which have the latest version of every structured product labeling document for products that are actively marketed.

[Reference](https://open.fda.gov/drug/label/reference/)

---

[National Library of Medicine (NLM) DailyMed SPL files](http://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/spl-resources-all-drug-labels.cfm)

---

[National Library of Medicine RxNorm API](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/research/umls/rxnorm/overview.html)